# Copy a single file to multiple folders with same name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a single file to multiple folders with same name using Powershell.
For example: I want to copy C:\test.html to D:\App ,but only to folders having the name of "Config" inside D:\App.

How can I do this using Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -path D:\App -Directory -filter Config -recurse|
  ForEach{Copy-Item C:\test.html -Destination $_.FullName -whatif}
```

If the output looks ok remove the `-whatif`